# Showing specific error in JSP with Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to show in my App different errors when a user is already logged in and when the user wrote their username/password wrong. I have tried many ways but none of them is working. I don't know what else to try or if it's even possible. I don't know if I'm close to the solution either.
What I'm trying to do is:

- Set the errorMessage in the request;
- Set the *SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR* in the response so the AJAX function enters in ** and the HTML in the paramether is the one in the JSP with the specific Message.

**Action**

```
public class LogUser extends Action {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        ...
        String pageToGo = this.tryLogUser(username, password);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(pageToGo).forward(request, response);
    }

    private String tryLogUser(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        String pageToGo = "page/userHome";
        ...
        if(canLog) {
            ...
            try {
                ...
                Server.getInstance().logIn(user); // Throws an Exception if the User is already logged in.
                ...
            } catch (ServerException e) {
                this.setErrorMessage("That user is already logged in.");
                pageToGo = "page/error.jsp";
            }
        } else {
            this.setErrorMessage("User and/or Password are incorrect.");
            pageToGo = "page/error.jsp";
        }
        return pageToGo;
    }

    private void setErrorMessage(String message) {

        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", message);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"> ${ requestScope.errorMessage } </div>
```

**AJAX**

```
function showUserHome() {
    $.post( "${ sessionScope.ServletUrl }", $( "form#logForm" ).serialize() )
    .done(function( html ) {
        $( "div#toolbar" ).load("page/userToolbar.jsp");
        $( "div#content" ).html( html );
    })
    .fail(function( html ) {
        $( "#result" ).html( html );
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

While trying to Debug it from the browser, it gets in the *$.post* and after that step, it jumps to the end of the function, skipping *.done* and *.fail* and the page remains the same. I'm not getting any error in the RAD Console or the Browser Console other than the *SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR* that I setted on the Action.

Comment: `not working` isn't a proper problem description especially when you have 2 separate environments communicating together. Need to be far more specific

Comment: Added a description of the problem. It's better or should I add something else?

Comment: From the edit it sounds like you aren't preventing browser default form submit and page is reloading

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setErrorPage` method won't change your `pageToGo`  local variable and thus always the same view is used. Change it to something like:

```
pageToGo = setErrorPage("That user is already logged in.");
```

(or even consider rename it to `getErrorPage`)

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to check that before copying the code. Updated the code making sure that the variable value is changed. Copypasting mistakes.

Comment: I would add logs in both server and client code to verify and check the network tab in browser to check if http post request was sent to correct URL and if expected response comes back.